# Camel JailStartingDirectory example

Tags: apache-camel

I want to use the camel jailStartingDirectory feature to write the file outside of FTP server mapped/home directory. I have gone through the camel documents, but not able to find any example for usage.

Can someone please help me on this.

My route look like this-

```
from(file://<file-path>/?move=../processed&moveFailed=../failed&sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle=true)
.to(sftp://xx:22?binary=true&username=xxx&privateKeyFile=xxx)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should set `jailStartingDirectory=true` on the FTP endpoint. And then the file name should be a relative file name, eg `../foo/myfile.txt` to save the file outside the starting folder. You can set/change the file name via the `CamelFileName` header; eg `Exchange.FILE_NAME` as constant.

Comment: In my case, I can have multiple files on "file://" location, so how can I provide the filename to each. should I pass the outside directory path as sub directory?